# AngularJS: How to load the template of a file into a page if the url of the template is stored in a variable name?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which creates some dynamic layouts in an existing page based upon type of element clicked in the page. The type of element clicked is sent by this directive to a controller. Based upon which the controller identifies the template url. This url is being sent to another directive which is used as an attribute, in the dynamic layout created by the first directive. Hence the template is loaded.
The first time the right template is loaded but from second time onwards it does not override for the new layouts but the same template is being used every time.

```
**Directive 1: editproperty:**

oldId = event.target.id;
             var split =  oldId.split("_");
              var fn = $scope.prop({elemtype : split[1]});  
 pe = ($compile('<div  id="fb_propeditor" ' +   ' class="fb_propeditor" ' + ' style="margin-top:' +  marginTop + 'px;">' + '<div id="fb_propeditor-head" > FIELD PROPERTIES</div>' + ' <div id="fb_propeditor-body" **setproptemplate**></div> </div>')($scope))
                angular.element(editorBox).append(pe);

**Controller:** 
 indApp.controller('EditPropertyController', ['$scope', 'fieldService' , function ($scope, fieldService) {

 $scope.handleProperty = function(elemtype) {

 fieldService.getTemplate(elemtype);

  }  
 $scope.$on('handleProperty', function() {
    $scope.propertyTemplate = propertyTemplate;
  });


}]);

**Directive 2: setproptemplate:**

 indApp.directive("setproptemplate", function()
 {

 return {
         restrict: "A",
    scope: {    propertyTemplate: "="   },  
   templateUrl: propertyTemplate

    };

 });

**HTML:** 
 <div ng-controller="EditPropertyController">
 <div id="fb_accum"  editproperty prop="handleProperty(elemtype)">

few elements here which are clicked

</div>
 <div id="fb_propertyEditorBox">

new layout gets created here in which the tempate is to be loaded

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your config code in which you have mentioned the routing?

Comment: Hi Mayank, my config code is: var indApp = angular.module("indApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource','dndLists', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies', 'ipCookie' ]);